# Google Fit permission

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to show a "connect to fit" button on the main screen, but only if it's not connected yet.

How can I check this, because if I connect my client and it's not approved, the app asked for permissions. Setting a shared pref isn't the solution, because the user can revoke the approval later in the system settings (outside the app).

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the [documentation for google fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization):

I think it is the design that user consent is needed every time your app access data (read/write).

Furthermore, to obtain authorization, you need to do the following:

> - [Register your Android app](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) with a project in the Google Developers Console.
> - Specify a scope of access when connecting to the fitness service.

Comment: This is only half the truth. I need every time to connect the the api client. That's right. But I want to know upfront, if the permission screen will be shown or not with the connect. And if the user needs to give permission I want to show a "connect now" button. Once the user approved the access, it will never show any permission screen.